# Setting up Touch Events on Materials in Papervision

Tags: actionscript, touch, papervision3d

I am working with papervision and would like to setup a TouchEvent on each side of a Cube. How would i go about it ? Right now i am setting up the events on the movieclip which i pass to the MovieMaterial class. The MouseEvent is working fine but the TouchEvent doesn't seem to fire.

```
     public function MiniCube(k:int, j:int, i:int)
    {
        var matList:Object = {all:new ColorMaterial(0xff0000,1,true)};
        matList.back = createColorMC(0x000000,'back');
        matList.front = createColorMC(0x000000,'front');
        matList.top = createColorMC(0x000000,'top');
        matList.bottom = createColorMC(0x000000,'bottom');
        matList.right = createColorMC(0x000000,'right');
        matList.left = createColorMC(0x000000,'left');

        cube = new Cube(new MaterialsList(matList),10,10,10);


    }


    private function createColorMC(color:uint, name:String):MovieMaterial
    {

        var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName(iconArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * iconArr.length)]) as Class;
        var mc=new ClassReference();
        mc.name = name;

         //MOUSE EVENT WORKS
        mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMovieMatClicked);

        //TOUCH EVENT DOESNT
        mc.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onMovieMatClicked);

        var movieMat:MovieMaterial = new MovieMaterial(mc,true,true);
        movieMat.interactive = true;
        movieMat.smooth = true;
        movieMat.animated = true;
        return movieMat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable multitouch on your application? The following line goes in the constructor of your main application class:

```
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```

or

```
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have added                                        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;  and the toucevents work for stage. Does papervision even support touchevents?